# Accessing specific database from a reference db in asp.net mvc c#: Works on localhost, but not on the live server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, dbcontext

Recently, I was asked to tranfer a mvc c# website onto an azure server.  I changed my connection strings to point to the new database, which is an exact copy of the old one:

```
    <add name="FBContext" connectionString="data source=NEWSQLSERVER;initial catalog=DefaultLocation;user id=username;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="LocationContext" connectionString="data source=NEWSQLSERVER;initial catalog=LocationRegister;user id=username;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="ManagerContext" connectionString="data source=OLDDEVSERVER;initial catalog=ManagerTables; user id=username;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Notice how "FBContext" is set to "DefaultLocation"?  That has to do with the way that the server is structured. There is one "Master" reference db that has all other dbs referenced in it.  The program accesses them by constructing a new connection string:

```
public string BuildConnectionString(string LocID)
        {
            Corporate CorporateRecord = null;

            if (LocID.Length != 10)
                throw new Exception("LocID Parameter formatted incorrectly.  Must be 10 characters long"); 
                try
                {
                    CorporateRecord = (Corporate)HttpContext.Current.Cache["FBManagerService_LocID_" + LocID];
                } catch
                {

                }
                if (CorporateRecord == null || CorporateRecord.DBName.Length == 0)
                    CorporateRecord = getRecord(CID); 

                if (CorporateRecord == null)
                    throw new Exception("Corporate Connection String not found based on LocID");

                if (CorporateRecord.DBName.Length == 0)
                    throw new Exception("No Database Found in ManagerContext");

            return "Data Source=NEWSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=" + CorporateRecord.DBName + ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password";
        }
```

This method of gernerating a new connection string is consumed by this Entity Framework Model:

```
public partial class FBContext : DbContext
    {
        public FBContext()
            : base("name=FBContext")
        {
        }

        public FBContext(string newConnectionString) <-- CONNECTION STRING GENERATED IN THE PREVIOUS CODE SNIPPET
         : base(newConnectionString)
        {

        }

        //Various EF dbsets.
    }
```

THE PROBLEM:

When I run the program in my Local Host on visual studio, everything works fine.  However, when I try and put the code on the live server, I cannot read ANYTHING from the database pointed to by "FBContext".  Does anyone have a clue as to why that might be happening?

Please be gentle, guys.  I'm going nucking futs over this, and I'm new to both c# and mvc.

Comment: when you run the code locally is the database still on a remote server or it local as well? Also are you getting any error message back from the server or are the queries just returning null record sets?

Comment: The database is always on that server.  I get no errors from the server, just null data sets.  Empty lists, in my case.

Comment: I ran into an odd issue once when pushing a site to the server the connection strings in the web.config file where getting truncated and wound up missing the provider key word. Look at the config files on your local machine then look at them on the server and make sure the connection strings are the same. I was using entity framework and it did not like the default provider...needs to be providerName="System.Data.EntityClient". see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619848/entity-framework-providername-in-connection-string-required-all-of-the-sudde

Comment: Would be helpful to understand what you mean by moving a web site to Azure. Are you using IAAS (VMs) or PAAS services? If OLDSERVER and NEWSERVER are VMs in Azure, are they in the same Resource Group and subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we publish a web project with database to Azure, we usually use Azure SQL. Azure can not call local SQL, because the local SQL  just stays in your local computer. It has not published to azure with web project. And the data in these two databases are not transmitted. Their design structure is different.

After you published a web project with Azure SQL, the Azure SQL just copy table structures of local SQL, but there is no data in tables. You need to create data to Azure SQL again. For more details about Azure SQL Database, you could read this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-migrate-your-sql-server-database) . And you could read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase) to publish Azure SQL with web project.