# How to use newly created database from azure cloud for identity in .Net application?

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I have created .NET application where I have used Identity to auto generate tables for registration and login.

I got connection string from azure cloud which I pasted it in web.config. Then I started `enable-migrations` to migrate but it following

> > PM> enable-migrations
> >         Migrations have already been enabled in project 'Aayumitra'. To overwrite the existing migrations configuration, use the -Force
> >     parameter.
> >         PM> update-database
> >         The connection string 'AayumitraDBConnection' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName
> >     attribute."

In IdentiyModel,

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("AayumitraDBConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

And web.config

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AayumitraDBConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:aayumitra.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=AayumitraDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />   
  </connectionStrings>
```

where am I going wrong? I am newbie to azure.

Comment: It is an entity framework specific question

Comment: @Thomas, how to resolve this issue. Can you please guide me. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: check this post, you need to add `providername` attribute to your connectionstring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619848/entity-framework-providername-in-connection-string-required-all-of-the-sudde

Comment: @Thomas, thank you. The `providername` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dummy connection string in Web.config and then overwrite it:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DataContext" connectionString="dummy" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You cannot omit connection strings from your web.config entirely. There must be a connection string in web.config with the same name. The value of the string does not matter but it must exist and it must have providerName set to System.Data.EntityClient.

Regards,

Pratik

Comment: It's glad that it worked. Please up vote the answer ☺️